# CDI 1.2 (WildFly 8.2), javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<SomeIFace> does not get beans which do not implement SomeIFace directly

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi, wildfly

I am already stuck solving injection of bean implementations into `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<SomeIFace>`. I have couple of beans (EJB Singletons) which extend an abstract class which implements the SomeIFace - see the scenario below.

```
public interface SomeIFace {

    void doStuff();
}
```

Then there is an abstract class adopting the `SomeIFace` as follows:

```
public abstract class SomeAClass implements SomeIFace {

    @Resource
    private TimerService ts;

    public TimerService getTimerService() {
        return ts;
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout() {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Actual implementation of a managed bean extends the abstract class `SomeAClass` as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class SomeClass extends SomeAClass {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in another class I want to get references to all managed beans implementing the `SomeIFace`, i.e.:

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<SomeIFace> beans;
```

The problem is that the `beans` is empty!

When I add the `SomeIFace` to the implementing bean class explicitly again (i.e. `public class SomeClass extends SomeAClass implements SomeIFace`), the `beans` is not empty and a reference appears.

Is anyone able to explain, why I need to repeat the `SomeIFace` interface directly on bean implementations again to get CDI 1.2 working? In previous version of CDI it was working fine.

Thank you in advance!

Jiri

UPDATE:

This strange injection issue happens only for beans which are EJB Singletons (`@javax.ejb.Singleton`). When the bean is annotated with `@javax.inject.Singleton` or `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` then it is not needed to repeat the interface declaration and beans are discovered OK. However, the `TimerService` can not be injected into non-EJB beans

Comment: Hmm doesn't sound right.  Are all of these in the same WAR? Any JAR files involved here?

Comment: Yes, all are in the same WAR, actually in the same JAR file

Comment: It also happens is Glassfish, and happen to any EJB (Singletone or Stateless), during my test im able to inject Instance<AbstractEJB> beans, but as soon as i introduce an interface to define a Local view, that bean  not longer appear in the list of beans @Inject Instance<AbstractEJB> beans. A way to solve this to mark explicitly the EJB implementation with the Interface directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the new behaviour is as specified in [CDI 1.2 Spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html):

> [3.1.2](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#managed_bean_types): The unrestricted set of bean types for a managed bean contains the bean class, every superclass and all interfaces it implements directly or indirectly. (...)
>   [3.2.2](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#session_bean_types): The unrestricted set of bean types for a session bean contains all local interfaces of the bean and their superinterfaces. If the session bean has a no-interface view, the unrestricted set of bean types contains the bean class and all superclasses. (...)

Note the difference in the definition of bean type for managed beans and session beans.

- For managed (non-EJB) beans, the spec explicitly states that "all directly or indirectly" implemented interfaces are a bean type of the bean. To me, this means that `SomeIFace` (which is implemented by `SomeAClass`, which is extended by `SomeClass`) would be a bean type of `SomeClass`, if `SomeClass` was a managed (non-EJB) bean.
- For session (EJB) beans, the spec is a bit vague in my eyes. However, to me, "all local interfaces of the bean" reads like the interface `SomeIFace` is only a bean type of the EJB `SomeClass`, if `SomeClass` directly implements it (as opposed to it only extends `SomeAClass` which, in turn, implements `SomeIFace`).
- But also note that, if you add `SomeIFace` directly to `SomeClass`, the bean *cannot* be injected via `@Inject SomeClass` anymore! This is as only if "the session bean has no-interface view", the bean class itself is a bean type -- otherwise, only "all local interfaces of the bean and their superinterfaces" (and `java.lang.Object`) are bean types.

Therefore, the behaviour you observe conforms to the spec.